# Enter password only once for shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have made a shell script to update & upgrade my existing packages all in one go. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update;
sleep 10;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
sleep 10;
sudo youtube-dl -U;
sleep 10;
sudo shutdown -h now;
exit 0
```

The problem I am facing is that as my internet connection is not very fast, by the time it reaches to the third command, the password session expires and I have to re-enter my password. And for that I have to be infront of my PC the whole-time which actually defeats the purpose of the script.

**So, my question is**:

> Is there anyway by which I can store the password in a variable and on
>   every `sudo` the password is entered from the variable so that I don't
>   have to be near my computer the whole time? (or anything similar that
>   would do what I want)

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Please enter your password: ";
read -s password
sudo apt-get update;
$password
sleep 10;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
$password
sleep 10;
sudo youtube-dl -U;
$password
sleep 10;
sudo shutdown -h now;
$password
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the sudo from the commands in the script, and run the actual script as root, eg.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update;
sleep 10;
apt-get upgrade;
sleep 10;
youtube-dl -U;
sleep 10;
shutdown -h now;
exit 0
```

And run it with `sudo ./my-script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to put in the password once. For the `apt-get` commands, the following has the `-y` flag set "Automatic yes to prompts" for everything but `dist-upgrade`.

```
sudo bash -c "apt-get -y update && apt-get dist-upgrade && youtube-dl -U && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y autoclean && shutdown -h now"
```